# Regex expression to match all char inside

Tags: regex

I'm trying to mass update a web app, I need to create a regex that matches:

```
lang::id(ALLCHARACTERS]
```

Can someone assist me with this?  I'm not good with regex.  I'm pretty sure it can start like:

```
lang\:\:\(WHAT GOES HERE\]
```

Comment: In what language are you using the regex?

Comment: `.` means any character. So `.*` is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lang::id\(.*]`

The `.` means any single character, and then `*` repeats it zero->N times.  Make sure to escape the `(` since it is used inside regex and is a special char for them, so escaping it with `\` is needed, or the regex will probably complain about unbalanced parenthesis.

If you wanted it to not include all characters, you can add a smaller regex in place of the `.*`.  This way you can break the regex down into smaller chunks which help make it easier to understand and develop for some complex rules.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
lang::id\([^]]*]
```

This will match a literal `lang::id\(`, followed by zero or more of any character *other than* `]`, followed by a literal `]`.

Note that the only character that really needs to be escaped is the open parenthesis.